# Modern OpenGL Projection View Model transformation not working

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl

I tried to use just one transformation (and its inverse transpose) in my shader, but my shading comes out all weird, so I guess my normals were transformed incorrectly. A lot of online tutorials propose using "projection * view * model" three-stage transformation, and calculate light during the "view * model" transformation stage. So I tried to implement these three transformations, but not only my teapot does not show, even a simple triangle won't show.

Here's my vertex shader code:

```
#version 410

in vec3 position;  // position of the vertex (and fragment) in world space
in vec3 normal;  // surface normal vector in world space

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 modelView_it;

vec3 l_pos = vec3(10, 10, 10);

out VertexData {
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 eye;
    vec3 lightDir;
} VertexOut;

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);

    VertexOut.normal = normalize(vec3(modelView_it * vec4(normal, 0.0)));
    VertexOut.lightDir = l_pos - vec3(pos);
    VertexOut.eye = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

And here's my fragment shader code

```
#version 150

out vec4 colorOut;

vec3 kd = vec3(0.1, 1, 0.1);
vec3 ka = vec3(1, 1.0, 1.0);
vec3 ks = vec3(0.5, 1, 0.5);
float sp = 90;
vec3 intensity = vec3(1, 1, 1);

in VertexData {
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 eye;
    vec3 lightDir;
} VertexIn;

void main()
{
    vec3 n = normalize(VertexIn.normal);
    vec3 l = normalize(VertexIn.lightDir);
    vec3 e = normalize(VertexIn.eye);

    vec3 diffuse = kd*intensity*max(0, dot(l, n));
    vec3 r = -l + 2*dot(l,n) * n;
    vec3 specular = ks*intensity*max(pow(dot(r, e), sp),0);

// force to be white intentionally to test
    colorOut = vec4(1,1,1,1);
}
```

Here are some functions I used to generate projection and view transformation matrices (code taken from some other similar stack overflow questions)

```
//generate projection matrix
void setPerspective(float fovY, float aspect, float near, float far, Matrix4f& mProjectionMatrix)
{
    float theta = fovY*0.5;
    float range = far - near;
    float invtan = 1./tan(theta);

    mProjectionMatrix(0,0) = invtan / aspect;
    mProjectionMatrix(1,1) = invtan;
    mProjectionMatrix(2,2) = -(near + far) / range;
    mProjectionMatrix(3,2) = -1;
    mProjectionMatrix(2,3) = -2 * near * far / range;
    mProjectionMatrix(3,3) = 0;
}
//generate view matrix
void lookAt(const Vector& position, const Vector& target, const Vector& up, Matrix4f& mViewMatrix)
{
    Matrix3f R;
    R.col(2) = (position-target).normalized();
    R.col(0) = up.cross(R.col(2)).normalized();
    R.col(1) = R.col(2).cross(R.col(0));
    mViewMatrix.topLeftCorner<3,3>() = R.transpose();
    mViewMatrix.topRightCorner<3,1>() = -R.transpose() * position;
}
```

Here's how I create and set the uniforms

```
// Create transformation matrices
Transform3fAffine trans = IdentityTransform();
Matrix4f viewMat = Matrix4f::Zero();
Matrix4f projMat = Matrix4f::Zero();
setPerspective(45.0f, //field of view
               4.0f / 3.0f, //aspect ratio
               0.1f, //near clipping
               100.0f, //far clipping
               projMat); //matrix
lookAt(Vector(3,3,3), //camera position
       Vector(0,0,0), //target to look at
       Vector(0,1,0), //up vector
       viewMat);
GLint viewID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
GLint modelID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
GLint projID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
GLint mvIT_ID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modelView_it");
transformModel(modelID, mvIT_ID, trans.matrix(), viewMat);
transformView(viewID, mvIT_ID, viewMat, trans.matrix());
transformProj(projID, projMat);
```

Those "transformXXX" functions look like this

```
void transformModel(GLint& modelID, GLint& mvIT_ID, Matrix4f& modelMat, Matrix4f& viewMat) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelID, 1, GL_FALSE, modelMat.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvIT_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, (viewMat*modelMat).inverse().transpose().data());
}

void transformView(GLint& viewID, GLint& mvIT_ID, Matrix4f& viewMat, Matrix4f& modelMat) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewID, 1, GL_FALSE, viewMat.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvIT_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, (viewMat*modelMat).inverse().transpose().data());
}

void transformProj(GLint& projID, Matrix4f& projMat) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projID, 1, GL_FALSE, projMat.data());
}
```

Despite all these, the screen is just nothing but black. Not even using a simple triangle at origin. If I get rid of `proj * view *` in my vertex shader (basically having "model" is the only transformation), I am able to see my shape and use keyboard events to transform it fine. This means that my basic pipeline shouldn't be the problem, as I'm able to see the shape. As soon as I add "proj * view * " before "model", everything blacks out.

Please help!

Update: now I have located one problem: `glUniformMatrix4fv` is giving me `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error, and it's not setting the uniform variable at all. (I verified this by hardcoding the matrix into the shader). I can hardly find any online issue and it seems like no one gets INVALID_ENUM error with this function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `transformXXX` functions look odd. Why are there 3 different ones? Normally the model, view and projection transformations go together. And both  transformModel`and`transformView` set the modelview_IT  matrix.

Normally you do not pass model and view transformation matrices as individual uniforms. For one in not well optimized shader code this would force to perform a 4×4 matrix-matrix multiplication for each vertex, which the result can easily be precomputed.

You should really merge `transformModel` and `transformView` into a single `transformModelView` function.

Another thing that looks odd is, that you're starting from zero matrices. Normally you initialize matrices with *identity* and work from there.

Comment: OK, found a potential issue: `glUniformMatrix4fv` inside my `transformXXX` always gets `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error, and silently fails (therefore not even setting the uniform to begin with, I also verified this by hardcoding the matrix inside shader, turns out that the uniforms are not set). Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Dovizu: How did you retrieve the error (invalid enum is not an error produced by `glUniform…`)? A little known faxt is that OpenGL errors accumulate. You must call `glGetError` in a loop until it returns `GL_NO_ERROR`. Chances are you've accumulated some other errors from OpenGL misuse before and you're seeing that in addition.

Comment: I tried to loop through errors, and the only one I get is 0x500 INVALID_ENUM. So you suggested that INVALID_ENUM is not an error produced by `glUniformMatrix4fv`. Then that aside, do you know why when I hard code the matrix into shader, something appears on screen (just flashes, at least not black), and if I set those uniforms in code, it won't work?

Comment: @Dovizu: My best bet would be, that one of the OpenGL calls you make earlier fails, and that this triggers a chain of failures that ultimately prevents you from setting the uniform. Add error checking to each and every OpenGL call, so see where it fails.

Comment: @Dovizu: Oh, and since you're using classes: Make sure you actually have the OpenGL context being active in the thread when those methods are called. Especially code called through constructors can get called at times that are rather unintuitive for newbies.

Comment: Just tried to add error checking in critical functions before I set uniforms, I actually didn't get anything until I set uniforms. This is pretty interesting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50859/discussion-between-dovizu-and-datenwolf)

Answer (score -1):

*Matrix operation order is mind-boggling to many, I am one among them*

In theory you want a vertex to be Modeled, Viewed, Projected and Put onto the screen. The code looks like it does just that.

You might want to look at your projection matrix

```
mProjectionMatrix(3,2) = -1;
mProjectionMatrix(2,3) = -2 * near * far / range;
mProjectionMatrix(3,3) = 0;
```

and try Transposing it.

```
mProjectionMatrix(2,3) = -1;
mProjectionMatrix(3,2) = -2 * near * far / range;
mProjectionMatrix(3,3) = 0;
```

One more thing you can do is to compare your matrices with gl implementation by setting them up with `gluPerspective` and then getting them by `glGet`.

Comment: There's nothing mind-boggling about the fact that the model-view transformations that occur in model and world space should occur before the whole scene is squeezed into the view frustum. And if you want a reference implementation like you suggested, I'd just use GLM.